# Storing data in each date in a month within a database

Tags: database, database-design

I'm creating a program that besides what the program does it also provides statistic information. One thing I wanted to add was number of transactions per day and then have maybe a line chart that shows how the transactions changed by day(within a month), then by month, then by year. I just can't really figure out how to convert that into a database that the program could pull that data and put it into a chart

Would be it be something like or is there something i'm missing:?

Day table;
(A.I)id, daynumber, dayofweek, numoftrans foreign keys: monthnumber , yearnumber

Month table

(A.I)id, monthnumber, nameofmonth, numoftrans

year table

(A.I)id, yearnumber, numberoftrans

Comment: if each transaction has a timestamp, i think there is no real need to create tables to store data that could be deduced with requests unless statistics should be historized & recalled beyond transaction record lifetime in db.

Comment: Well the program is sorta like a library program. You "Sign in" and "sign out" items and if you keep out an item longer the the assigned amount of time (72hrs within a week). Then the program notifies the admin. I wanted there to be some historical data so that the admin could look at the chart and be able to tell how many times people signed out things on any given day, month, year because maybe sometime in the future the admin would want to increase or decrease the amount of hours users could take out items or maybe change a rule based on the day of the week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you *need* is a table that stores dates and number of transactions.

```
create table transactions_per_day (
  transaction_date date primary key,
  num_transactions integer not null check (num_transactions >= 0)
);
```

The number of transactions per month and per year can be done in a query with aggregate functions (SUM()) and a WHERE clause.  For the total per month . . .

```
select
  extract(year from transaction_date) tr_year, 
  extract(month from transaction_date) tr_month, 
  sum(num_transactions) num_tr
from transactions_per_day
where transaction_date between '2013-01-01' and '2013-12-31'
group by tr_year, tr_month
order by tr_year, tr_month;
```

It often makes sense to create views for the monthly totals and the annual totals.

```
create view transactions_per_month as
select
  extract(year from transaction_date) tr_year, 
  extract(month from transaction_date) tr_month, 
  sum(num_transactions) num_tr
from transactions_per_day
where transaction_date between '2013-01-01' and '2013-12-31'
group by tr_year, tr_month
order by tr_year, tr_month;
```

Comment: Thank you! This way makes A LOOOTT more sense. The way I was thinking about it just seemed wrong. Thank you for your time.